# In Elm, how would you get every even index in a list and return as another list?

Tags: elm

In Elm, how would you get every even index in a list and return as another list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to return only even-indexed items from a list, right?

Here's how you could do that writing your own function. We'll write a helper function, `everySecond_`, that looks like this.

```
everySecond_ : List a -> Int -> List a
everySecond_ list index =
    case list of
        [] ->
            []

        hd :: tl ->
            if index % 2 == 0 then
                hd :: (everySecond_ tl (index + 1))
            else
                everySecond_ tl (index + 1)
```

This function takes a list, and a number representing what index the current head  of that list has. We need to pass that as an argument to the function.

Then we pattern-match on the list. If it's empty, we return an empty list; this signals the end of recursion. The last element in a list is always an empty list. If it's *not* an empty list, we take the head (the first element) and the tail (a list representing everything onward).

If our `index` argument was even (`% 2 == 0` means "when divided by two, leaves no remainders"), we want to keep this element, so we append it to the front of the list we're building up, and continue to build by calling `everySecond_` again with the tail of our current list and an incremented index number.

If it's *not* even, we don't want to keep this element, so we just return `everySecond_ tl (index + 1)`, the next stage of the list, and the process repeats.

That's the logic of it. But that means we'd need to call `everySecond_ [foo, bar, baz] 1` to use our function, always passing in 1 as a default argument. That's not intuitive. And that's why we called it `everySecond_` with an underscore -- this isn't what we're going to have people call, this is a helper function that'll exist behind the scenes. We can hide this behind

```
everySecond : List a -> List a
everySecond list =
    everySecond_ list 1
```

Now you call `everySecond [foo, bar, baz]` and it works fine, basically defaulting the starting index to 1.

An even simpler way of doing this would be to not keep track of the index at all, but to use a boolean (True/False) value. You start with a False, and instead of testing for divisibility by 2, you just check the boolean. If it's True, you keep the element, and call the function again with False; if it's False, you ignore the element and call the function again with True.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, you do not need to program recursive functions because you can make use of standard helper functions which do that for you. Here is such a solution to your specific problem:

```
takeEvenIndexes : List a -> List a
takeEvenIndexes l =
  l
  |> List.indexedMap (\ i x -> if i |> modBy 2 == 0 then Just x else Nothing)
  |> List.filterMap identity
```

The [`indexedMap`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/List#indexedMap) function is like a `map` but you can depend on the index of the value as well. And [`filterMap`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/List#filterMap) is like a map but you can discard some of the values by returning `Nothing`. Here it is applied to the [`identity`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Basics#identity) function because the filtering has already been pre-computed on the previous line.